# How to add "Other Linker Flags" to xcode project using command line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to automate building process of xcode project. The problem is that I need to add "Other Linker Flags" when building the project. I can't just add it to the project Build Settings manually, I have to do it using the command line.
May be I can edit the project file or configuration file somehow?
Any options are good as long as it can be runned as a script.
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by specifying an xcconfig file to xcodebuild. For example:

```sh
echo 'OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -force_load "$(SRCROOT)/calabash.framework/calabash" -lstdc++' > temp.xcconfig
xcodebuild -xcconfig temp.xcconfig ...
```

Comment: how do I set this flag: -force_load "$(SRCROOT)/calabash.framework/calabash" -lstdc++   ?

Comment: I get the error when I try to build the project using 'xcodebuild' :  The following build commands failed:
 Libtool build/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/foo.build/Objects-normal/armv6/foo.a normal armv6.    Even though the project builds fine when I add linker flags manually in xcode

Comment: If it builds in Xcode fine, you probably should be able to build it with xcodebuild if you specify the right scheme/target/configuration, etc. Take a look at the xcodebuild docs or you could open a new question.

Comment: can you add more than one linker flags?  like -ObjC?

Comment: @Frank Yep - the example I gave passed several linker flags (-force_load and -ldstdc++); you can just add more on there.

Answer (score 2):

@Jesse Rusak's answer works, but it is a bit simpler to directly add options to the command line, being careful to escape variables from your shell like

```
xcodebuild ... "OTHER_LDFLAGS=\$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -all_load"
```

Answer (score -1):

open up the project.pbxproj file in an editor like BBEdit and paste in the flags you want. Search for

```
buildSettings = {
...

SWIFT_VERSION = 4.2;
}
```

becomes

```
buildSetting = {
...

SWIFT_VERSION = 4.2;
OTHER_LDFLAGS = "-all_load";
}
```

There should be a section for your Debug and Release schemes. Do it for all